# How do I install pip on CentOS?

Tags: centos, python, python3, pip

I'm using CentOS 7.  I want to use Pip to install a virtualenv .  So I installed Pip like so ...

```
[laredotornado@server Python-3.7.2]$ sudo yum install python-pip httpd mod_wsgi
[sudo] password for laredotornado: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fileplanet.com
 * extras: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * updates: mirror.fileplanet.com
No package python-pip available.
Package httpd-2.4.6-88.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mod_wsgi-3.4-18.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

but then when I actually try and use pip, i'm told it can't be found ...

```
[laredotornado@server Python-3.7.2]$ sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo: pip: command not found
```

How do I properly install pip on my Linux distro?

Comment: Do you have an EPEL repository added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarised from [another site](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/):

Core package repositories for CentOS 7 does not have `python-pip`.  For that you need to enable an EPEL ("Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux") repository.  You do that with

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

After that, you should be able to install `pip` with

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

Also possibly related:

- [How to install pip in CentOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618686/how-to-install-pip-in-centos-7) (on StackOverflow, old)
- [Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408941/recommended-way-to-install-pip3-on-centos7) (on StackOverflow, newer)

In particular, one answer there states that

> Since Python 3.5, `pip` is already bundled with the python distribution, so you can just run `python3.6 -m pip` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Also, you can do “python3 -m venv” instead of using pip to install virtualenv in the first place.

Comment: I've installed epel, done `yum update/upgrade`, and yum still can't find python-pip.

Answer (score 1):

alternate solution:

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: For Python 3.4: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.4/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py`